# Get row from a table by td class and specific value in the cell in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to find the row in multiple table which has specific value in a hidden td which has a class name

```
<table>
   <tr>
    <td class="id hidden">16</td>
    <td class="maintenance_date">30 Jun 2014</td>
    <td class="station_code">TSK</td><td class="gear_code">T1</td>
    <td class="role_name">INCHARGE SSE/SE</td>
</tr>
<table>
```

there will be multiple rows in the table or tables. For Example, I want the rows with the text 16 only on the td which has class id hidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty simple:

```
var searchTerm = 16;
var elements = $('td.hidden').filter(function() {
      return $(this).text() == searchTerm;
 }).parent();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
var td16_row=$('td').filter(function(){
    return $(this).text()=="16";
}).parent();
```

Comment: that could return the tbody

Comment: @ShivanDragon Then that would be an invalid html.

Comment: @ShivanDragon: why will it return tbody.

Comment: so it will return tr and not tbody

Comment: @MilindAnantwar yes, sorry, my mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would have done something like this (NOT tested)

```
var elements = $("table tr").find(".id.hidden").html();

$.each( elements, function( key, value ) {
  if (parseInt(value) === 16) {
      //do something with $(this)
  }
});
```